# Found nil for optional value?

Tags: swift

I just can not figure this out :

```
print(module)
print(Globals.sharedInstance.dataModuleName)
let kind:NSString = module[Globals.sharedInstance.dataModuleName] as! NSString
```

Will print this, and then crash for a strange reason:

```
( //dic print
        {
        meta = no;
        module = IN;
        subject = LT;
        variable = A2;
    }
)
module    // print the right field we are looking for inside the dictionary .
```

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

But you can see that module is a valid dictionary and also `dataModuleName`.

Crashing on the line `let kind`. What's wrong with it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your module is `Array` of `Dictionary` not directly `Dictionary`, so you need to first access its first object then the module key like this

```
let kind:String = module[0][Globals.sharedInstance.dataModuleName] as! String
```

**Note:** One sugeestion, in swift use `String` instead of `NSString`

Also you can use `if let` and `guard` with initializtion to avoid crash.

Comment: Thank you very much, but I'v checked this out and its a dictionary, I create a dictionary called data with     var data:NSMutableDictionary=[:]

Comment: The way it is printing it is dictionary inside array, Try once like my answer.

Comment: Sorry this is right, thank you very much ! will accept when it lets me.